# Trace not working on Callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback, trace

I have a web page with a custom user control. The user control contains a data grid and other controls. On clicking a row of the grid a callback occurs opening a new user control with details of the grid row clicked. This is working sometimes very slowly so on the parent page I set Trace to true and put Trace.Warn at the beginning and end of the event in the first user control that creates and removes the second user control. When I run the page I get the trace information but when I click the grid row and create the detail user control the trace information doesn't change and I don't see any Trace.Warn information. Does Tracing work only on postbacks not on callbacks? How can I find out where the slowing is happenning? I'm using devexpress controls.

Comment: paste some code what you tried

Comment: Your Control may handle the grid row->details on the client side, and your tracing could be server side only.

Consider also javascript tracing, like adding onClick="alert('Hello from JavaScript!')" to your control elements.

Comment: @ Pieter21 Clicking the grid row activates a client event which activates a server callback. Shouldn't that affect the trace?

Comment: Post some of the code you tried. Especially how you start/open the trace destination, and how you call it in the controls. Maybe you have unopened or competing traces.
To attract more audience, you could also change the subject a bit.

Comment: I put trace=true in the aspx mark up of the parent page. The user control ascx page doesn't accept Trace definning. I placed a Trace.Warn in the c# code Page_Load of the first userControl and also tried putting in the c# code of the callback event that creates the second user control. I also put trace enabled in the web.config. Non of that caused any reaction in the page out put or in the trace.axd.